# How is the Fiery Burst feat targeted?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, targeting

We had a discussion in my D&D 3.5e round yesterday about *Fiery Burst* (reserve feat from *Complete Mage*).

From the feat's description, it does not require (1) a line of sight nor (2) the invoker to be able to target anything. It just states that you can create a burst within range.

Is that correct? We were confused because (1) means I could create the burst behind doors or walls and (2) that I could do that very precisely even while blinded, which feels wrong.

Is there anything in RAW about how these supernatural abilities are targeted?

**Clarification:** By "while blinded" I mean if I can tell the blinded mage to burst something "20 feet ahead of him".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### It acts as an area-of-effect spell (5' spherical burst).

It is true, you do not need to have line of sight to a grid intersection you target, but you have to have line of effect<sup>1</sup>. So you can't "cast" it to the other side of total cover (wall, closed door, etc).

As for inability to see where you target your feat's ability but still accurately hitting right squares, all things which are targetted by grid do exactly that, so there is no surprise Fiery Burst can do it.

---

1. Originally, the concept of line of effect is for spells, but this is because initially PHB authors didn't expect PCs to have unusual abilities besides spells or something like that. Many crucial pieces of information are given in the way they apply to spells (and without further clarification it is unclear if *only* to spells). Fortunatly, Rules Compendium (and later reprintings of PHB maybe) fixes much of that. Rules Compendium p.80 gives the following definition of line of effect:

   > Line of effect tells you whether an effect, such as an explosion,
   >   can reach a particular target. A line of effect is a straight,
   >   unblocked path that indicates what an **ability, effect, or spell**
   >   can affect. A solid barrier cancels line of effect. Fog, darkness,
   >   and other factors that limit normal sight don’t block
   >   line of effect[...]